# How to write mapping/settings for an index using elastic4s?

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

```
PUT /new_index/
{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "type": "default"
        },
        "number_of_shards": 5,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "ap_stop": {
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords_path": "stoplist.txt"
                },
                "shingle_filter" : {
                    "type" : "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size" : 2,
                    "max_shingle_size" : 5,
                    "output_unigrams": true
                }
            },
        "analyzer": {
             "aplyzer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "tokenizer": "standard",
                "filter": ["standard",
                           "ap_stop",
                           "lowercase",
                           "shingle_filter",
                           "snowball"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PUT /new_index/document/_mapping/
{
    "document": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "string",
                "store": true,
                "index": "analyzed",
                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
                "search_analyzer": "aplyzer",
                "index_analyzer": "aplyzer"
            },
            "original_text": {
                "include_in_all": false,
                "type": "string",
                "store": false,
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "docid": {
                "include_in_all": false,
                "type": "string",
                "store": true,
                "index": "not_analyzed"  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to convert the above index `settings` and `mappings` to the type accepted by `elastic4s`. I am using latest `elastic4s` and `elasticsearch 1.5.2`.

I went through some examples given in the documentation but I can't figure out how to do it like I tried to create it this way:

```
client.execute {
    create index "new_index" mappings {
      "documents" as (
        "text" typed StringType analyzer ...
        )
    }
  }
```

I cannot figure out how to use `store`, `index`, `term_vectors` etc. as given in the PUT request.

**UPDATE:**
Based on the answer I was able to make this kind of a thing:

```
create index "new_index" shards 5 replicas 1 refreshInterval "90s"  mappings {
    "documents" as(
      id typed StringType analyzer KeywordAnalyzer store true includeInAll false,
      "docid" typed StringType index "not_analyzed" store true includeInAll false,
      "original_text" typed StringType index "not_analyzed" includeInAll false,
      "text" typed StringType analyzer CustomAnalyzer("aplyzer") indexAnalyzer "aplyzer" searchAnalyzer "aplyzer" store true termVector WithPositionsOffsetsPayloads
      )
  } analysis (
    CustomAnalyzerDefinition(
      "aplyzer",
      StandardTokenizer,
      LowercaseTokenFilter,
      shingle tokenfilter "shingle_filter" minShingleSize 2 maxShingleSize 5 outputUnigrams true
    )
  )
```

what I cannot figure out now is how to add snowball stemmer and stop words file path to the `aplyzer` analyzer?

How should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what @monkjack suggested and what I read from `elastic4s`'s documentation I finally came up with following answers to what index settings and mappings would look like when used with `elastic4s`. Go through the [tests](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/1d6b8decda7b82703dfd0c90fd5be592d1bbeebd/elastic4s-core/src/test/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/CreateIndexDslTest.scala) that the author has written for the API.

```
create index "new_index" shards 5 replicas 1 refreshInterval "90s" mappings {
    "documents" as(
      id
        typed StringType
        analyzer KeywordAnalyzer
        store true
        includeInAll false,
      "docid"
        typed StringType
        index "not_analyzed"
        store true
        includeInAll false,
      "original_text"
        typed StringType
        index "not_analyzed"
        includeInAll false,
      "text"
        typed StringType
        analyzer CustomAnalyzer("aplyzer")
        indexAnalyzer "aplyzer"
        searchAnalyzer "aplyzer"
        store true
        termVector WithPositionsOffsetsPayloads
      )
  } analysis (
    CustomAnalyzerDefinition(
      "aplyzer",
      StandardTokenizer,
      LowercaseTokenFilter,
      NamedStopTokenFilter("ap_stop", "_english_", true, true),
      shingle
        tokenfilter "shingle_filter"
        minShingleSize 2
        maxShingleSize 5
        outputUnigrams true
        outputUnigramsIfNoShingles true,
      snowball
        tokenfilter "ap_snowball"
        lang "English"
    )
  )
```

Use `StopTokenFilter("ap_stop", stopwords = Set("a", "an", "the"))` in place of `NamedStopTokenFilter` if you wish to give your own list of stopwords.

I get the following setting/mapping when I run `GET new_index` in Sense.

```
{
   "new_index": {
      "aliases": {},
      "mappings": {
         "documents": {
            "properties": {
               "docid": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "store": true,
                  "include_in_all": false
               },
               "original_text": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed",
                  "include_in_all": false
               },
               "text": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "store": true,
                  "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
                  "analyzer": "aplyzer"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "settings": {
         "index": {
            "creation_date": "1433383476240",
            "uuid": "6PmqlY6FRPanGtVSsGy3Jw",
            "analysis": {
               "analyzer": {
                  "aplyzer": {
                     "type": "custom",
                     "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "ap_stop",
                        "shingle_filter",
                        "ap_snowball"
                     ],
                     "tokenizer": "standard"
                  }
               },
               "filter": {
                  "ap_stop": {
                     "enable_position_increments": "true",
                     "ignore_case": "true",
                     "type": "stop",
                     "stopwords": "_english_"
                  },
                  "shingle_filter": {
                     "output_unigrams_if_no_shingles": "true",
                     "token_separator": " ",
                     "max_shingle_size": "5",
                     "type": "shingle",
                     "min_shingle_size": "2",
                     "filler_token": "_",
                     "output_unigrams": "true"
                  },
                  "ap_snowball": {
                     "type": "snowball",
                     "language": "English"
                  }
               }
            },
            "number_of_replicas": "1",
            "number_of_shards": "5",
            "refresh_interval": "90s",
            "version": {
               "created": "1050299"
            }
         }
      },
      "warmers": {}
   }
}
```

If you want `StopWords` and `Stemmers` as separate Analyzers, as @monkjack suggested just add `SnowballAnalyzerDefinition` and `StopAnalyzerDefinition` like:

```
....outputUnigramsIfNoShingles true,
    ),
    SnowballAnalyzerDefinition("ap_snowball", "English"),
    StopAnalyzerDefinition("ap_stop", stopwords = Set("a", "an", "the"))
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your title asks about custom filters, but your question body asks about `store`, `index`, and `term_vectors`. I will explain the latter.

```
  client.execute {
    create index "myindex" mappings {
      "mytype" as (
        "myfield" typed StringType store true termVector termVector.WithOffsets index "not_analyzed"
        )
      )
    }
  }
```

**Update**:

Based on your updated question. The elasticsearch documentation isn't clear on if you can have stopwords set on a snowball token filter. You can on a snowball analyzer.

So, either

```
SnowballAnalyzerDefinition("mysnowball", "English", stopwords = Set("I", "he", "the"))
```

or

```
CustomAnalyzerDefinition("mysnowball",
  StandardTokenizer,
  LowercaseTokenFilter,
  snowball tokenfilter "snowball1" language "German"
)
```

Comment: I was able to do that looking at the test scripts in the source. One thing I want to confirm is there is a type of `term_vector` which is `with_positions_offsets_payloads` and I think in my version I don't have it. Should it be added to `domain.scala` as `case object WithPositionsOffsetsPayloads extends TermVector("with_positions_offsets_payloads")`?

Comment: Yes that's missing, I've just added it to master.

Comment: Based on your answer and documentation I was able to get what I have added in the update. I have a small doubt as well that I have mentioned there. Could you please help me out with that?